# Solutions of 1D-Dirac equation for free particle only have positive energy solutions?

Tags: dirac-equation, eigenvalue

Im studying the (stationary) free 1D-Dirac equation

$$H\Psi(x) =(mc^2\sigma_1-i\hbar c\sigma_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x})\Psi(x) = E\Psi(x),$$

where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_3$ are the pauli matrices.

I was able to determine the (unnormalized) solutions

$$\Psi_1(x) = \binom{1}{\frac{mc^2}{E-pc}}e^{-ipx/\hbar}
 \quad \text{and} \quad \Psi_2(x) = \binom{\frac{mc^2}{pc+E}}{1}e^{-ipx/\hbar},$$

where $E=\sqrt{m^2c^4+c^2p^2}$.

I'm wondering, why do I get $H\Psi_1 = +E\Psi_1$ and $H\Psi_2 = +E\Psi_2$? Shouldn't one of the two eigenstates have a negative energy eigenvalue, i.e. $H\Psi = -E\Psi$?

Comment: Your equation only has 2 components. The Dirac equation is a 4-component equation.

Comment: yes this is due to the fact that this is the one dimensional equation. the gamma matrices are in the 1d case the 2x2 pauli metrices. Therfore the Eigenstates are 2 dimensional vectors.

Comment: I was also wondering, why there are only 2 components. I think this is because in the 1d case there is no angular momentum, and therefore there is no such thing as spin. So i thought the 2 orthogonal vectors represent each the positive and negative energy case.

Comment: Isn't this more like Weyl equation?

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are actually identical up to normalization. If you multiply your $\Psi_1$ by $\frac{mc^2}{pc+E}$ you get what you are calling $\Psi_2$.

In this solution $E$ and $p$ are only fixed by the condition $E^2= p^2c^2+m^2c^4$, so for any given $p$ there are two solutions for $E$ of differing sign. This is the sense in which there are two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Idea on how to get the negative energy states. When I calculate the Energy, I get the condition $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$.

So I can define $E = \pm \sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4} = \pm E_p$ and therefore I have two different differential equations:

$H\Psi_+ = +E_p\Psi_+$ and

$H\Psi_- = -E_p\Psi_-$

the second equation should give me the negative energy states.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Yes your idea is correct

Comment: Yes I did I just didn't saw the fact that I actualy get two equations in your comment. As you may noticed, I'm not very experienced so sorry for not seeing this :)